# dot product (cosine similarity) between a mixture of numeric and categorical values in r

Tags: r, distance, cosine-similarity

I have a data frame where each row is an observation and each column is a feature. I would like to calculate the similarity between observations. For purely numeric features this would be the equation:

[image]

where P1 and P2 are two observations. Now, let's say that for categorical features I define the product between two vectors in that particular dimension as 1 if they have the same category in a particular dimension and -1 if they have different categories; see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4433333/

How can I prepare the original data frame to automate the calculation? e.g. say the data frame contained only two features: age and university department, so that:

```
df <- structure(list(Age = c(18, 20, 23, 29, 19, 21, 23), Department = c("history", 
"math", "biology", "math", "math", "history", "history")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show how would your expected output look for this example?

Comment: @RonakShah it should be a distance matrix